# can't understand variadic templates in c++

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

I was reading about variadic templates and I came across this example. The book mentions that to end the recursion process, the function `print()` is used. I really can't understand its use. Why does the author use this empty `print()` function?

```
void print () // can't get why this function is used
{
}

template <typename T, typename... Types>
void print (const T& firstArg, const Types&... args)
{
    std::cout << firstArg << std::endl; // print first argument
    print(args...); // call print() for remaining arguments
}
```

Comment: After the last argument is printed the "empty" print() will get called.

Comment: Do you understand recursive functions? If not, variadic templates will be too advanced a topic.

Comment: @MSalters i get recursive functions completely and i have updated the question

Comment: @rahultyagi I undid your update. First, you have good answers to a straightforward question - so don't change your question. If you want to ask a new question, ask a new question. Second, the update made no sense.

Comment: @rahultyagi: Just add a `std::cout<<`  statement to the empty print function, and see for yourself what it does.

Comment: @Barry the update made sense since it asked about an exceptional case ,as it is perfectly logical to wish for a parameterless function if you dont knw the exact number of parameters ,all i wanted to ask if that would be possible or not in c++

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A variadic expression can capture *0 arguments or more*.

Take for example the call `print(1)`. Then `T` captures `int` and `Types = {}` - it captures no arguments. Thus the call `print(args...);` expands to `print();`, which is why you need a base case.

---

You don't need the recursion at all. I always use the following `debuglog` function in my code (modified for your needs):

```
template<typename F, typename ... Args>
  void
  print(const F& first, const Args&... args) // At least one argument
  {
    std::cout << first << std::endl;
    int sink[] =
      { 0, ((void)(std::cout << args << std::endl), 0)... };
    (void) sink;
  }
```

Because this variadic function takes at least one argument, you are free to use `print(void)` for whatever you like now.

Comment: Yeah... that work around recursion makes the code much uglier than having a bit of code duplication.

Fortunately, C++17 will have fold expressions

Comment: @WorldSEnder thats the perfect answer i was looking for.

Comment: "for whatever you like now" -> but does `print(std::endl);` work?

Answer (score 4):

It is recursive because the variadic part of the template is reduced each call, for example a call would recursively look like this

```
print(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)  // firstArg == 1
                      // ...args == 2,3,4,5

print(2, 3, 4, 5)     // firstArg == 2
                      // ...args == 3,4,5

print(3, 4, 5)        // firstArg == 3
                      // ...args == 4,5

print(4, 5)           // firstArg == 4
                      // ...args == 5

print(5)              // firstArg == 5
                      // ...args == {}

print()
```

The `print()` is necessary as a base case for when the variadic list is empty.

Answer (score 3):

Consider a call to the template function with a single argument.

```
print(1);
```

`firstArg` would bind to the `1` (`T = int`), and `Types...` would bind to nothing. A variadic argument pack is *zero* or more arguments.

Thus, in this call:

```
print(args...);
```

`args...` is an empty parameter pack. So it expands into:

```
print();
```

Since your function template matches any call to print with *one* or more arguments, you need a separate function to handle zero arguments. Which in this case is the trivial function:

```
void print () { }
```

Answer (score 3):

Assume the following code:

```
int a, b, c;
print(a, b, c);
```

The compiler will implicitly create the following code:

```
print(const int& firstArg)
{
    std::cout << firstArg << std::endl; // print first argument
    print(); // call print() for remaining arguments
}

print(const int& firstArg, const int& arg2)
{
    std::cout << firstArg << std::endl; // print first argument
    print(arg2); // call print() for remaining arguments
}

print(const int& firstArg, const int& arg2, const int& arg3)
{
    std::cout << firstArg << std::endl; // print first argument
    print(arg2, arg3); // call print() for remaining arguments
}
```

as you can see in the version with only one argument, the compiler will call a "print" method with no arguments. Since the variadic print function ALWAYS requires at least one parameter this will not match...

Comment: The last sentence is slightly wrong -- you probably meant "Since the **function with** variadic template  ALWAYS [...]".